# How to send data from parent component to child component in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems to be a pretty straightforward problem, but I haven't got it's answer for quite a while. The question is, when you have a hierarchy of components, how do you pass data from parent component to child components so that the children are able to access that data in their scope (or in some other variable?)

I am using AngularJs 1.5.5

Here is the plunker of what I have right now, I have added comments inside the JavaScript code about what I actually want to achieve. - https://plnkr.co/edit/blY85rvARIqkmfCnRBOV?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <dependency></dependency>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('myApp', ['dependency']);

// this is parent component
angular.
module('dependency', ['dependency2']).
component('dependency', {
  templateUrl: 'dependency.html',
  controller: ['$scope', function dependencyController($scope) {
    $scope.dependencyScopedVariable = "Some local variables of dependency";
    $scope.childComponentParams = [{ name: "child1"}, { name: "child2"}];
  }]
});

// this is child component
angular.
module('dependency2', []).
component('dependency2', {
  templateUrl: 'dependency2.html',
  controller: ['$scope', function dependency2Controller($scope) {
    // How to access childParam from parent here?
    $scope.itemGotFromParent = "this should be from parent";
  }]
});
```

dependency.html

```
<div>{{dependencyScopedVariable}}</div>
<dependency2 ng-repeat="childParam in childComponentParams"></dependency2>
```

dependency2.html

```
<!-- How to get the childParam repeated in ng-repeat here? -->
<div>{{itemGotFromParent}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are making use of component and that itself is a sugar syntax of the directive.
You can 
1) `require` the controller of the parent component. For more info read [intercomponent communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)
2) Pass the data as the `bindings`.

Look at the following example:

Example#1:

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('myApp', ['dependency']);

// this is parent component
angular
  .module('dependency', ['dependency2'])
  .component('dependency', {
    template: '<div>{{$ctrl.dependencyScopedVariable}}</div>' +
      '<dependency2 ng-repeat="childParam in ' + '$ctrl.childComponentParams"></dependency2>',
    controller: function dependencyController() {
      this.dependencyScopedVariable = "Some local variables of dependency";
      this.childComponentParams = [{
        name: "child1"
      }, {
        name: "child2"
      }];
    }
  });

// this is child component
angular.
module('dependency2', [])
  .component('dependency2', {
    require: {
      dependencyCtrl: '^dependency'
    },
    template: '<div>{{$ctrl.itemGotFromParent}}</div>',
    controller: function dependency2Controller() {
      
      this.$onInit = function() {
        this.itemGotFromParent = this.dependencyCtrl.childComponentParams;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <dependency></dependency>
</div>
```

Example#2: Using component's bindings(scope in directive)

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('myApp', ['dependency']);

// this is parent component
angular
  .module('dependency', ['dependency2'])
  .component('dependency', {
    template: '<div>{{$ctrl.dependencyScopedVariable}}</div>' +
      '<dependency2 data="childParam" ng-repeat="childParam in ' + '$ctrl.childComponentParams"></dependency2>',
    controller: function dependencyController() {
      this.dependencyScopedVariable = "Some local variables of dependency";
      this.childComponentParams = [{
        name: "child1"
      }, {
        name: "child2"
      }];
    }
  });

// this is child component
angular.
module('dependency2', [])
  .component('dependency2', {
    bindings: {
      data: '<'
    },
    template: '<div>{{$ctrl.itemGotFromParent}}</div>',
    controller: function dependency2Controller() {

      this.$onInit = function() {
        this.itemGotFromParent = this.data;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <dependency></dependency>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, this looks like one of the solution. Two questions: 
1) 'pass the data as the scoped variable' or 'require the controller of the parent component' are the two approaches same?
2) Here, every child has access to whole array of `childComponentParams`. Can't we pass one element of this array to each child based on index?

Comment: Let me correct myself when I mentioned 'pass the data as the scoped variable', what I meant was to use `bindings` as that what angular is calling for `component`. Secondly, both the approaches are different and I've added Example#2 that demonstrates this technique. And I you can pass individual element I guess by making some clever use of `ng-if`.

Comment: One more thing, when use `require` you have access to the controller instance itself and by that, you have access to whatever you have on the `this` object of that controller.

Comment: I think the second approach is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: When I am using this approach in my actual code, (which isn't much different from above), I'm getting $ctrl is not defined error. I think the ng-repeat works fine and correct number of instances of `dependency2` are created. However, inside $onInit, this.data is undefined.

Comment: Where do you get ' $ctrl is not defined' error. Can you share your code?